# How to put skimage imread_collection through tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, scikit-image

I'm trying to put a collection of images through a neural network, but I can't figure out how to get a large collection of images to go into a tensorflow model, as trying to convert the collection into a numpy array causes a memory error.

I should note that I am very new to tensorflow.

```
import numpy as np
from skimage.io import imread_collection
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers

def gen(arr):return(i.reshape(400*600*3) for i in arr) # Only used in Attempt2.

labelFile=open("lables_text_file.txt","r")
labels=labelFile.read()
labelFile.close()
labels=getTrain(labels)#Converts to a tuple containing the lables in order.

data = imread_collection("path_to_images/*.jpg", conserve_memory=True)
train=data[:-len(data)//4]
trainLabels=labels[:-len(data)//4]
test=data[-len(data)//4:]
testLabels=labels[-len(data)//4:]

#train = train.reshape(-1, 400*600*3) # Attempt1
#test = test.reshape(-1, 400*600*3) # Attempt1
#train = gen(train) # Attempt2
#test = gen(test) # Attempt2
trainLabels = keras.utils.to_categorical(trainLabels, 23)
testLabels = keras.utils.to_categorical(testLabels, 23)

model=keras.Sequential([keras.Input(shape=(400*600*3,)),
        layers.Dense(600, name='hidden1', activation='relu'),
        layers.Dense(400, name='hidden2', activation='relu'),
        layers.Dense(46, name='hidden3', activation='relu'),
        layers.Dense(23, activation="softmax")])

optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0015)
model.compile(loss=keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(), optimizer=optimizer, metrics=[keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy()])
model.fit(train,trainLabels,batch_size=128,epochs=8,validation_data=(test,testLabels), shuffle=True)
```

When I run the code as is, this is the result:

```
ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: <class 'skimage.io.collection.ImageCollection'>, <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

When I try to use Attempt1, this is the result:

```
AttributeError: 'ImageCollection' object has no attribute 'reshape'
```

When I try to use Attempt2, this is the result:

```
ValueError: `y` argument is not supported when using python generator as input.
```

How can I put the data into `model.fit, such that it will successfully train the neural network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I may have solved the problems.

Working code:

```
import numpy as np
from skimage.io import imread_collection
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers

def gen(arr,labels):return((arr[i].reshape(-1,400*600*3),labels[i].reshape(-1,23)) for i in range(len(arr)))

labelFile=open("lables_text_file.txt","r")
labels=labelFile.read()
labelFile.close()
labels=getTrain(labels)#Converts to a tuple containing the lables in order.

data = imread_collection("path_to_images/*.jpg", conserve_memory=True)
train=data[:-len(data)//4]
trainLabels=labels[:-len(data)//4]
test=data[-len(data)//4:]
testLabels=labels[-len(data)//4:]

#train = train.reshape(-1, 400*600*3) # Attempt1
#test = test.reshape(-1, 400*600*3) # Attempt1
trainLabels = keras.utils.to_categorical(trainLabels, 23)
testLabels = keras.utils.to_categorical(testLabels, 23)
train = gen(train,trainLabels) # Attempt2
test = gen(test,testLabels) # Attempt2

model=keras.Sequential([keras.Input(shape=(400*600*3,)),
        layers.Dense(600, name='hidden1', activation='relu'),
        layers.Dense(400, name='hidden2', activation='relu'),
        layers.Dense(46, name='hidden3', activation='relu'),
        layers.Dense(23, activation="softmax")])

optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0015)
model.compile(loss=keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(), optimizer=optimizer, metrics=[keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy()])
model.fit(train,None,batch_size=128,epochs=8,validation_data=(test,testLabels), shuffle=True)
```

The solution was to pass in a generator that returns two-tuples containing the input and label (instead of passing the labels in directly), but there were other problems that I may include in this answer if I get the time.